# jQuery, infinite scroll, isotope - loop a function and break when outside variable changes

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, nested-loops, infinite-scroll

Some sample js code:

```
var $ = jQuery,
    $container = $('#gridcontainer');
    done_loading = false;

$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#navi',
    nextSelector : '#navi a',
    itemSelector : '.grid-item',
    errorCallback : function () { 
        done_loading = true;
        console.log(done_loading);
    },
    // call Isotope as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
        $container.isotope( 'insert', $( newElements ) ); 
    }
);  

$('a.my_test_button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( $('#gridcontainer div.isotope-item:not(.isotope-hidden)').size() < 15 && done_loading == false ) {
        $container.infinitescroll('retrieve');
        console.log('loaded');
    }
}
```

This code sets up an infinitescroll with isotope, and loads more elements when user scrolls to bottom. Now, when isotope filter is used, some elements are hidden, so when I load more elements on some pages there might be no elements of a filtered kind.
So this is where my `a.my_test_button` should go into play and load more items till infinitescroll `errorCallback` fires and sets `done_loading` to true (all pages have been loaded, so there is nothing more to load) or number of not hidden elements is more then 15.

But the code above does it once, and I would like this part to loop till above conditions met.

How should I change this code to be abble to make described loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('#gridcontainer div.isotope-item:not(.isotope-hidden)').size() < 15 && done_loading == false ) {
    $container.infinitescroll('retrieve');
    console.log('loaded');
}
```

change to

```
while ( $('#gridcontainer div.isotope-item:not(.isotope-hidden)').size() < 15 && done_loading == false ) {
    $container.infinitescroll('retrieve');
    console.log('loaded');
}
```

you can try with this.

```
do{ 
   $container.infinitescroll('retrieve');
   console.log('loaded');
  }while( $('#gridcontainer div.isotope-item:not(.isotope-hidden)').size() < 15 && done_loading == true );
```

Comment: I thinkt there will be a problem with infinitescroll, which need some time to load new items, and putting it in the while loop might kill the app ;).

Comment: I have added a code, if you see then you will find that i have used done_loading == true to be sure than it has used enough time to load new items. That might help.

Comment: done_loading fires only when there is no more items to load (with blog, when You reached oldest post)). Sadly there is no way to check, when infinitescroll finish current loading sequence :( (for now I have used setTimeout with 500ms to be shure items are loaded).